# Como usar "wildcard" em seletores de "CLASSE" com jQuery.expr?

Tags: jquery

O seletores de classe como `.exemplo` ou seletores separados por espaçamento `[atributo~=valor]` **se comportam totalmente diferente de seletores como:**

- `[atributo=valor]`
- `[atributo*=valor]`
- `[atributo^=valor]`

O `.exemplo` e `[atributo~=valor]` buscam valores separados por espaços. O que eu preciso é de um seletor customizado com `jQuery.expr` para buscar valores separados por espaços, mas que seja possível usar caractere *wildcard* **semelhante** ao `%` do `LIKE` em mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

A ideia é fazer algo como (semelhante):

```
$(".js-use-?").length //Retorna 4
```

Ou semelhante:

```
$("[class~=js-use-?]").length //Retorna 4
```

Ele pegaria qualquer classe que tive-se `js-use-2`, `js-use-palavraqualquer`, `js-use-3`, etc.

No caso o `?` será o *wildcard*, mas poderia usar `%` também, por exemplo:

```
$(".js-use-%").length //Retorna 4
```

Ou então

```
$(".foo-%-hello").length
```

O caractere *wildcard* é irrelevante, pode ser qualquer coisa, desde que o comportamento de valores separados por espaços seja o mesmo que os seletores já citados `.exemplo` e `[atributo~=valor]`

> **Note:** o seletor por ponto (`.`) não pega apenas atributos como `<div class="foo">`, ele pega também `<div class="alpha foo betha">`, ou seja ele pega o atributo dividido por "espaço".
>   Mais detalhes em http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html

Isto é possível com jQuery?

Comment: Oficialmente a jQuery suporta os seletores das CSS3, que são esses que você já conhece. Infelizmente não há coringas (wildcards) nesses seletores, por isso essa funcionalidade não é suportada oficialmente. Porém, encontrei essa extensão aqui que pode lhe servir, ela usa RegEx (Expressões Regulares): [http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/190255/1161005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Infelizmente todas outras respostas estão erradas**, conseguiram o comportamento do curinga/wildcard, mas não entenderam que o comportamento tem que ser como é o **seletor `.classe`**, assim como é em CSS2, CSS2.1 e CSS2.2

Tanto o seletor `.classe` quanto o seletor de atributo `[atributo~=valor]` **não se comportam como seletores de atributo normal**, eu expliquei e frisei isso bem na pergunta, neste ponto:

> > **Note:** o seletor por ponto (`.`) não pega apenas atributos como `<div class="foo">`, ele pega também `<div class="alpha foo betha">`, ou seja ele pega o atributo dividido por "espaço". Mais detalhes em http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html

Aliais segue o link da documentação básico para quem esta aprendendo CSS e quer entender as diferenças (ou confirmar o que eu digo):

- https://w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#attribute-selectors

---

### A solução

Para fazer um seletor que se comporte como o seletor de classes (ou este seletor `[atributo~=valor]`) do CSS com caractere *wildcard* semelhante ao `%` do `LIKE` em Mysql

A solução que cheguei irá se comportar como `.class` ou como , ficou assim:

```js
//Seletor customizado
jQuery.expr[':']['class-wildcard'] = function (elem, index, match) {

    //Separa as partes da string
    var parse = $.trim(match[3]).split('?');

    //Escapa os caracteres necessários
    for (var i = 0, j = parse.length; i < j; ++i) {
        parse[i] = parse[i].replace(/[-\][*+?)(:\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    // Gera a regex em formato de string
    var cls = '\\b' + parse.join('\\S+') + '\\b';

    return new RegExp(cls).test(elem.className);
};

console.log(":class-wildcard(js-use-?) -> ", $(":class-wildcard(js-use-?)").length);

console.log(":class-wildcard(foo?bar) -> ", $(":class-wildcard(foo?bar)").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- abaixo será com o seletor :class-wildcard(js-use-?) -->
<div class="foo js-use-1"></div>     <!-- será pego -->
<div class="js-use-2 bar"></div>     <!-- será pego -->
<div class="baz js-use-3 boo"></div> <!-- será pego -->
<div class="js-use-empty"></div>     <!-- será pego -->

<div class="foo wjs-use-1"></div>     <!-- NÃO será pego -->
<div class="xjs-use-2 bar"></div>     <!-- NÃO será pego -->
<div class="baz yjs-use-3 boo"></div> <!-- NÃO será pego -->
<div class="zjs-use-empty"></div>     <!-- NÃO será pego -->


<!-- abaixo será com o seletor  :class-wildcard(foo?bar) -->
<div class="foobazbar"></div>             <!-- será pego -->
<div class="fooxyzbar"></div>             <!-- será pego -->
<div class="fooabcbar"></div>             <!-- será pego -->
<div class="col1 foobazbar"></div>        <!-- será pego -->
<div class="col2 fooxyzbar custom"></div> <!-- será pego -->
<div class="fooabcbar col3"></div>        <!-- será pego -->
<div class="fooar col4"></div>            <!-- NÃO será pego -->
```

### Explicando o código

Para explicar melhor o código, o parse divide strings em arrays, assim:

- `js-use-?` vira `["js-use", ""]`
- `foo?bar` vira `["foo", "bar"]`

Desta forma é possível aplicar o "escape" nos caracteres que poderiam afetar a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) que ocorre dentro do `for()`:

```
parse[i] = parse[i].replace(/[-\][*+?)(:\\]/g, '\\$&');
```

Então depois ele junta com `.join` os arrays novamente usando como separador o `\S+` que será o curinga/wildcard no caso, a expressão `\S` ("s" em maiúsculo) é a negação de `\s`, ou seja o coringa pode ser qualquer coisa menos espaço, tab ou quebra de linha.

Note que também foi usado `\b` nas extremidades, um expresão assim:

```
\bfoobar\b
```

Seria *"semelhante"* a isto:

```
(^|\s)foobar($|\s)
```

Ou seja, o valor testado na regex deve começar e terminar com a palavra da expressão, ou deve conter espaços.

Então após o `join` os parâmetros teriam resultados como este:

- `js-use-?` vira esta regex `/\bjs-use-\S+\b/`
- `foo?bar` vira esta regex  `/\bfoo\S+bar\b/`
- `a?b?cde?xyz?` vira esta regex  `/\ba\S+b\S+cde\S+xyz\S+\b/`

Comment: +1 pelo esclarecimento

Answer (score 7):

<sub>**Nota:** Não faço ideia o que quer dizer "coringa" mas vou usar essa palavra no exemplo desta resposta.</sub>

O jQuery não faz isso naturalmente. Mas dá para extender o pseudo seletor `:` para fazer isso.

A funcionalidade poderia ser: `:coringa(<atributo>, <string com "?">)`.

O jQuery gauarda os métodos para pseudo seletores em `jQuery.expr[':']` e podes criar um novo simples criando uma nova propriedade nesse objeto.

A esse novo método é passado pelo Sizzle/jQuery o elemento, o index entre os seus siblings e o que está dentro desse pseudo-seletor como ultimo argumento.

O código para fazer isso seria assim:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].coringa = function(elem, index, match) {
    var parametros = match[3].split(' ').join('').split(',');
    var attr = parametros[0];
    var regexString = parametros[1].replace('?', '([a-zA-Z_\\-0-9]+)');
    var regex = new RegExp(regexString, 'ig');
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem).attr(attr));
}
```

E depois usar assim:

```
$(':coringa(class, js-?-empty)').css('color', 'red');
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9br4Lt3p/

Comment: Coringa é o mesmo que Curinga:  **Caracter, geralmente um asterisco (*), que pode representar qualquer outro caracter**

Comment: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/425/curinga-or-coringa

Comment: Coringa é muito usado no Brasil, por adaptação por causa do personagem do Batman, mas o correto mesmo é curinga, já corrigi o titulo na pergunta.

Comment: Haha, esse pt.se vai dar muito jeito aqui :) Podiamos abrir uma filial lá para termos de código :)

Comment: Sérgio, eu fico mesmo grato, sua resposta passou um pouco perto, mas sinceramente não é o comportamento do seletor de classe, então acabei eu mesmo elaborando uma resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322698/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vi somente agora a tua resposta, não tive tempo antes para ver com mais cuidado. ++

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta maneira que também funciona:

```
$(function() { 
    $('div').each(function() {
               var classes = $(this).attr('class');
               var arrClass = classes.split(' ');
                   arrClass.forEach(function(value, key) {
                      if ( value.indexOf('js-use') !== -1) {
                         $('.'+value).css('color','red');
                      }
                  });
    });
});
```

Aqui o **jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/9br4Lt3p/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Como já responderam, o `jQuery` usa os seletores que você mencionou:

`^=` *starts with* (começar com);
`$=` *ends with* (terminar com);
`*=` *contains*  (contém);

Nativamente são esses, mas existem extensões que permite usar coringas, ou *wild cards*, como essa por exemplo: [jquery-wildcard-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-wildcard-selector)

Permite fazer coisas como:

`$(':withWildcard(name, foo-*-*)')`

E no seu exemplo, **selecionando uma classe** (como está na pergunta: `$(".js-use-?")` fica assim:
`$(':withWildcard(class, js-use-*)')`

Comment: Caro Ricardo eu quero resolver para classes e não para atributos, o comportamento é diferente. Eu escrevi na recompensa: **"Aguardo mais sugestões que de preferencia se comportam como classe e não como atributo"**, ou seja classes não se comportam como atributos, o que eu quero é outra coisa. Por favor se puder editar a resposta para o que é pedido na pergunta eu ficaria agradecido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu tinha colocado um exemplo mas não estava claro, editei a pergunta e coloquei o exemplo específico para um seletor por classe, por favor veja se é o que você procura senão preparo um outro exemplo. Obrigado por apontar

Comment: Caro Ricardo, o problema é que classe não é atributo, da forma que você fez se comporta como atributo, você consegue entender como funciona "o seletor de classes"? Sabe que ele funciona bem diferente de seletor de atributos né? Não basta passar `:withWildcard(class` ai o comportamento é **como de um atributo** normal, não adianta de nada com o que é pedido na pergunta, aliais o unico seletor CSS (e querySelector) é o `[atributo~="..."]`. Talvez isso já ajude a você ter uma ideia.

Comment: Sim entendi @GuilhermeNascimento, realmente acaba se comportando diferente, ainda mais você precisar juntar algo como `+ elemento` ou `> elemento` não vai funcionar corretamente

Comment: Eu fico grato pela sua tentantiva, mas sua resposta não passou nem perto, pelo que eu já disse, isso `$(".js-use-?")` não é a mesma coisa que `$(':withWildcard(class, js-use-*)')`, o comportamento é totalmente diferente, eu elaborei uma resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322698/3635, se lhe interessar.